# How to use single URI for multiple table in content provider in android?

Tags: android

Right now i am on project which require to implement content provider which have multiple table! but I want to use single URI only! how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

During query, you can JOIN tables.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 USING (common_column);
```

In case of insert you have to put values separately to each table inside Content Provider.

Comment: hey thanks for help! but how can i point to these tables using URI?? i know the querries!

Comment: Use this select inside of query method of your Content Provider. If you do not know how to use Content Provider please follow Dev Guide.

Comment: Thanks! it means i dont require to create URI for each table! i got it! :)